# Why is the output of this program 0?

Tags: c

The output of the program below is 0, but why?

```
 #include <stdio.h>  
 #include <conio.h>  
 int main()  
 {  
        int x=5;        
        printf("%d",x!=5);  
        getch();  
 }
```

Comment: hmmm, !== is a strange oprator

Comment: !== is not an operator, I strongly doubt that your code has any output at all.

Comment: What's `!==`? did you mean `!=`?

Comment: Yes, I searched for !==. But not geting any result. Is it really an operator??

Comment: I can't even compile it under Linux. It rightly complains about `!==`. Judging by the inclusion of `conio` then this is Windows, right? Is this seriously allowed?

Comment: @Narendra no it's not.

Comment: It's a typo. He means `!=` and the result is `0` because `x` is not equal `5`.

Comment: !== is not an operator, i think you mean !=. you set x to 5, than you comapre x!=5, this fails, so your output is 0

Comment: Your condition is saying `if x is not equal to 5` but as you already set x=5 so condition is getting Failed so returning zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False is printed as `0`.

`x!=5` is false, hence `%d` will print `0`, if you do `x==5`, it will print `1`.

http://codepad.org/t8DAMu3A

Comment: AFAIK, true ist defined as "not zero", most compilers will print true as 1, but not guaranteed. true could be any number except 0.

Comment: True is not necessarily 1. It can be denoted by any non-zero value.

Comment: `c11` indeed says it as `1`.
From, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf : section 6.5.9.3,
`The == (equal to) and != (not equal to) operators are analogous to the relational operators except for their lower precedence.) Each of the operators yields 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is false. The result has type int. For any pair of operands, exactly one of the relations is true.`

Comment: @WoJo In a condition, every nonzero value is considered true, but all comparison operators (and the logical operators) return either 0 or 1, that is mandated by the standard.